# Programmatically get IIS server URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

#### Short version:

How can I get the URL of the server my MVC3 project is being executed on?  I do NOT want to hard code a server address.

#### Long version:

I've got three servers I will be working with:

1. Development server
2. QA server for others to test
3. Production server

None of the above servers have the same URL.

My web project needs to generate notification emails that contain a clickable link.

I know that Request.Url.ToString() will get me the server but if possible, I'd rather not spend time processing that string everytime I generate an email.

Comment: My hope is to be able to set it once during the Application_Start so that when I generate emails, all I have to reference is "myServerURL" with no checks.  But beggars will be choosers ;)

Comment: why not just have a parent method get it and pass it to the email generation routines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can process the `Request.Url` once and store the result in a static variable. Just make sure you access that variable in a thread-safe manner. I've been using this in production for quite a while, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to check if the static variable is empty for every email with this method?

Comment: Yes, because this is what lazy initialization does. But reading a static variable isn't exactly going to make your application slower...

Comment: This is probably the approach I will take... but, from a "speed" standpoint, would just reading Request.Url going to be faster than checking a static variable then reading it?

Comment: I don't know how it's implemented, and theory is a bad way to determine performance. However, this level of micro-optimization is rarely helpful. Step through an entire request w/ MVC and your db driver compiled as source and you get an idea how many calls they make - most of which are much more expensive.

Comment: @JohnStone `Request.Url` isn't a very expensive operation and it's evaluated only once per `Request` object. If one feels the need to micro-optimize, as mnemosyn implied, using a [`Lazy<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) object as the underlying static Server value, initialized on the first request, may be optimal enough. Constructors have options to control the thread safety level of `Lazy<>` initialization.

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

Should do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

Request.URI is the way to go. If you are really that worried about performance, profile it. I can almost guarantee the results wont be bad. If they are you can read it from the headers manually via Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] etc

Comment: Be careful about the `Request.Headers`: Sending the `HOST` header is mandatory in HTTP/1.1, but it's not in HTTP/1.0. Also, some clients (spam bots) just don't adhere to the standard, hence causing exceptions.

Comment: I was originally going to process the Request.URI each time I created an email but the "old" developer in me doesn't like redoing something that won't change ;)

Comment: Then simply reference it once and set it in a static var if you are that concerned with it, however since perf of it is very minimal and it already exists (created as part of your request) the hit is so small, there are other areas to be concerned with : )

Comment: @mnemosyn sure, in that case they dont get access to the system. Also using host headers on your server (which is quite standard now as almost no one gets a single ip anymore to host) would deny them access as they'd be addressing the rot.

Comment: @AdamTuliper: Maybe they wouldn't get access... Then again, maybe it'd throw an exception and flood your logs if you have a default binding - careful. Also, dedicated IPs are still pretty much required for SSL -- SNI is coming, but not commonplace.

Comment: @mnemosyn uc certs take care of the issue in iis. its not required to have a single name per cert.

Comment: @AdamTuliper: Interesting, I didn't know UC certs. Still, it's better to not assume there's no default binding in code if possible, don't you think? Otherwise the code is tied to the way the site is deployed. Also, UC certs seem to be made for a given number of previously well-known subdomains, so you'd still not be on the safe side for `*.domain.com` wildcard scenarios, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but I recently had to get the URL of the default website on IIS.  It proved to be a real pain, but I managed to get this working code...

```
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    private string GetDefaultSite()
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry w3svc2 = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://Localhost/W3SVC"))
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry de in w3svc2.Children)
            {
                if (de.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer" &&
                    de.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString() == "Default Web Site")
                {
                    string binding = de.Properties["ServerBindings"].Value.ToString();

                    string[] split = binding.Split(':');

                    if (split[2] == "") return "http://localhost/";
                    else return "http://" + split[2] + "/";
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Server Variables](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp), you can find the server name there.

`SERVER_NAME` could be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

One of these should work:

```
Response.Write Server.MachineName;
Response.Write Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

Comment: I tested both of these and I don't think either is appropriate.  Server.MachineName gives the actual name of the machine, not the URL of the machine.  LOCAL_ADDR seems to result in the IP addres.

Comment: Like Jani said, you can also use Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]; but keep in mind that people can still access your site via IP address or they can update their hosts file and use whatever name they want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);`. This will return the sever starting from http.... till the server name and port.